# $scope.formName.fieldName.$setValidity is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to set invalid with angular when firstname is equals to lastname and change the color using styles to red.

http://jsbin.com/japir/2

```
function RegoController($scope) {
  $scope.app = {
    firstName: "Saroj"
  };

  $scope.$watch("app.lastName", function(newVal, oldVal) {
    if (!!$scope.app.lastName && !!newVal)
      if (angular.lowercase($scope.app.firstName) === angular.lowercase(newVal)) {
        debugger;
        $scope.form.inputLastName.$setValidity("sameName", false);
      }

  });
}

<body ng-app>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="RegoController">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <form name="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputFirstName">First Name</label>
          <input id="inputFirstName" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="app.firstName" placeholder="Enter your firstname" required ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputLastName">Last Name</label>
          <input id="inputLastName" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="app.lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name" required ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
          <input id="inputEmail" class="form-control" type="email" ng-model="app.email" placeholder="Enter your email" required />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
        </div>
      </form>
      {{app}}
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to select a form input that has no name; thus making it unable to find the field you are trying to invalidate. Here is a working example:

JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/yozanado/1/

**Input field with name:**

```
<input id="inputLastName" name="lastName" class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="app.lastName" placeholder="Enter your last name" required ng-minlength="3" ng-maxlength="20" />
```

**Javascript:**

```
$scope.form.lastName.$setValidity("sameName", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS form validation relies on the name of the form and the name of the fields to find the validation models on scope.

For example, if your HTML is:

```
<form name="form">
     <input name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" />
</form>
```

You will be able to access the validation $error property on scope using the name attributes:

```
$scope.form.firstName.$error.sameName
```

To fix the issues you're having, add a name attribute to your input fields.

[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/cadiwuxa/2/edit)